# Conditionally generate Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I currently have an excel sheet that is used to record daily a bunch of parameters. Currently, I have a folder for each year, containing a folder for each month, inside of which I have an excel file with sheets corresponding to each day of that month.

What I am looking to do is to compress all of this into one excel file, mainly to make it easier to create formulas comparing days across different months.

Would it be possible to have a single excel sheet with a drop down menu, where you could select the date, with the rest of the cells in the sheets values being conditionally dependant on the date selected. i.e. blank if the date is in the future and there is no data, or containing the appropriate data from that day?

Comment: You seem to be looking for more of a database solution then a spreadsheet. Can you share a sample of your data?